# how to get url from which facebook page chat box starts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

We are using facebook messenger chat box from fb page on our website.
Our website is ecommerce store, but when customer start a chat and asking about product we don't see the url where is he on the site.

We try to look everywhere in the facebook page messages but we don't see this info anywhere.
Is there a way how to get it?
Thank you a lot for any advice.

Comment: The chat plugins all have a `ref` parameter, the value of which you can specify at the point where you embed the plugin. (I am not sure though, whether that value is accessible via the page inbox UI, or only when you process incoming messages via a webhook, you’d have to check.)

Comment: thx for answer.. we only see messages in fb page manager.. and we dont see `ref` parameter or setting how to track it anywhere.. im not sure how to "process incoming messages via webhook".. but thx anyway

Comment: With the latter, I was referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook, which is basically way a to get a script on your own server notified when anyone messages your page, enabling you to create your own system to handle the messages, outside of the FB UI.

Comment: ok.. now i understand.. but thats too complicate.. thx for your answers